# Partitioning a 2 TB GoDaddy Server with 16 gigs of ram into 3 virtual private servers

Tags: vps

I am interesting in partitioning a two terabyte Godaddy server that currently has centos 6.5 running on it. Currently paying $200 a month for this server but only use at most a 10th of its capacity. A lot of space and ram are never used plus I have 2 extra IPs that GoDaddy has given for me to add onto any future servers.

I want to partition this server into three virtual private servers. I don't want to touch the original centos 6.5 server but just add on two extra private servers each with a copy of Ubuntu.

I know this is possible but haven't managed to find any good tutorials or documentations showing how. Also performance-wise would this be just as reliable as having 3 seperate Godaddy servers with weaker spec but far cheaper?
Thanks.

Comment: What benefit are you imagining here? You'd still be using 10% of its capacity.

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to make use of the extra servers? If no, there's no point and you may as well downgrade to a less powerful server. I'd use something like KVM - [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117635/how-to-install-kvm-and-create-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu/) is a quick runthough on how to set up virtual machines. If you want, you could use VirtualBox instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVM on your server. First of all you must create a Bridge network over your interface in order to be able to distribute the other two IPs to the virtual machines. After you are finished you can install whatever OS you want on that virtual machines and create as many as you want (as long as you have memory to assign to them).

You can also use X-Forwarding in order to be able to have a graphical interface of virt-manager.